# How to format specific text

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to specifically format text based on the value in the "last vote" column on https://baefell.co/emc/lookup/zerofelero/table for when the last vote is more than 1 day. Specifically to highlight that table row red. Is this possible? How would I go about injecting/ replacing the CSS of said row based on said value? I plan on utilizing a Chrome Extension, and from my understanding, this would in theory encompasses HTML, CSS and javascript. I am fairly comfortable with HMTL and CSS basics, but don't really have any javascript experience.

Any help is much appreciated!